# Angular 7 - Another Wildcard routing not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I got this error when debugging routing:

```
 { path: 'login'                           , component : LoginComponent },
  { path : ''                               , component : DashboardComponent        , outlet: "main-route", pathMatch: 'full'},

  { path: '404'                             , component : PageNotFoundComponent     , outlet: "main-route"},
  { path: '403'                             , component : PermissionDeniedComponent , outlet: "main-route"},
  { path: '**'                              , redirectTo : '404' ,  pathMatch: 'full'}
```

This is my routes.

When I try: http://server_ip/not-exist

Im expecting to go to 404 page. 
However, I got this:

```
Router Event: NavigationStart
platform-browser.js:211 NavigationStart(id: 1, url: '/not-exist')
platform-browser.js:211 NavigationStart {id: 1, url: "/not-exist", navigationTrigger: "imperative", restoredState: null}
platform-browser.js:216 Router Event: NavigationError
platform-browser.js:211 NavigationError(id: 1, url: '/not-exist', error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'not-exist')
platform-browser.js:211 NavigationError {id: 1, url: "/not-exist", error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'not-exist'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/…}
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'not-exist'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'not-exist'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

Where im wrong?

UPDATE 2019/10/07

The Angular error is misleading. Angular needs a "non named" route. Then you can add a named outlet.
Then I have tried to trigger this outlet.

Now. Im including a sub-component with its own routes to be added to the main routes.

```
//app.routing

 {
    path: 'external-module',
    loadChildren: () => import('./external-module/external-module.module').then(mod => mod.ExternalModuleModule)
  },
[...]

//external module routing

    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path        : '',
        component   : ExternalModuleHomeComponent,
        outlet: 'sub'
      },
      {
        path        : 'second',
        component   : ExternalModuleSecondComponent,
      },
    ];



//layout.html
  <div style="padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px; border: 1px solid black;">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px; border: 1px solid red;">
      <router-outlet name="sub"></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

With this configuration, when I click on this button:

```
<button routerLink="/external-module">home</button>
```

ExternalModuleHomeComponent is correctly loaded in "sub" router-outlet

When I click on this button:

```
 <button routerLink="/external-module/second">second linik</button>
```

ExternalModuleSecondComponent is loaded in "primary non named" router-outlet AND the ExternalModuleHomeComponent is loaded in "sub" outlet (!!!!!).

Now. I want the SecondComponent to be loaded in "sub" router as its father.

I then tried simply adding outlet as father:

```
{
    path        : 'second',
    component   : ExternalModuleSecondComponent,
    outlet: 'sub'
  },
```

This solution DON'T WORK. I got the famous 404 page loaded.

I then tried to move the "second" route inside the father:

```
{
    path        : '',
    component   : ExternalModuleHomeComponent,
    children: [            
        {
            path: 'second', component: ExternalModuleSecondComponent, outlet: 'sub'
        }   
    ]    
    , 
    outlet: 'sub'
}
```

Another 404, even removing outlet : "sub" in the child.

Im really tired. There is no examples on internet with a sub-app routing inclusion like this.

Comment: Remove `pathMatch: full` from your fallback (`**`) route.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard route must be

1. `{ path: '**', redirectTo : '404'}` // if you like to redirect or
2. `{path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}` // show the component

> The wildcard route must be the last route among all routes whatever
>   application has multiple modules.

Think, you have multiple modules, and the `WildcardRoutingModule` has

```
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '**',
        component: redirectTo : '404'
    }
])
```

In the Root module, you should give the last position to `WildcardRoutingModule`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule, // included Root routes 
        SignInModule, // included Child routes 
        LayoutModule, // included Child routes
        AdminpanelModule, // included Child routes       

        WildcardRoutingModule // Since it has wildcardRouting, it should be the last Module among all other Routing module
    ],
    .....
})
export class AppModule {
}
```